# AX 2012 - How can I retrieve the labelid of a field

Tags: label, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I want to get the label of a field in a specific language.
This could be done through something like:
    SysLabel::labelId2String(literalstr('@SYS1'), 'en-us');

But to do so, I need the LabelId of the field, which I don't know how to retrieve.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer:

Apparently I should initiate a SysDictField object and call the labelLabel method.

```
    SysDictField df;

    df = new SysDictField(common.RefTableId, common.RefFieldId);

    info(SysLabel::labelId2String(df.labelLabel(),SystemParameters::getSystemLanguageId()));
```